# How to write Requirements for a specific module

Tags: requirements, specifications, modules

I am familiar with writing Software Requirements Specification, but not quite sure how to write the requirements for a specific module.

Let's say I need to develop a Reservation System and  there will be a module to perform validation. Now, an SRS is already available for the entire system, but prior to designing(API Specification and Class Diagrams) the Validation module, what would be the format of writing Requirements for this module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A specific model shouldn't require more requirements, a module should complete or be part of the solution to a subset of overall requirements for the project. If you find that a module doesn't work towards fulfilling project requirements, then it,s either unnecessary or your requirements are lacking. Creating modules is part of the design process, requirements should already have been set, if you are trying to make specific requirements for a specific module then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What I actually want to do is, create TFS Work Items. Now, I should be submitting the Requirements of a particular Task, or Module as needed. How to write this specific requirements for TFS Work Item?

Answer (score 1):

Like [Ryathal said in his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/135567/4), specific components shouldn't have their own requirements. However, it might be a good idea to provide traceability from the system architecture, the component's detailed design, and the implementation details back to the requirement(s) that drove that decision. All the design decisions and functionality implemented should be derived from some requirement of the system.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a business rules document.  This would define the rules that the system must enforce and follow.  Included in the business rules would be rules as to what is an acceptable reservation.  If you then are building a validation module, its purpose would be to enforce the business rules.

Take a look at http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/businessRule.htm